# Unable to a read a large file using BufferedReader in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file using BufferedReader, but when I tried to print, It is returning some weird characters.

Code of reading file is:

```
private static String readJsonFile(String fileName) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while(line != null ){
                sb.append(line);
                System.out.println(line);
                line=br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally{
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

This function is being called as :

```
 String jsonString = null;
    try {
        jsonString = readJsonFile(fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I tried to print this in console using `System.out.println(jsonString);`, It is returning some fancy pictures.

Note: It is Working file when file size is **small**.

Is there any limit on size of file it can read ?

Comment: What do you mean by "some fancy pictures"? What is the encoding of the file, and what's your platform default encoding? (Currently you're using `FileReader`, which always uses the platform default encoding... I'd suggest  using `Files.newBufferedReader` instead, which defaults to UTF-8 but allows you to specify the charset.) I'd also recommend using try-with-resources...

Comment: Do you have any binary data in your JSON, or is it all text?

Comment: What's the file's contents? You're likely trying to read a binary file as plaintext.

Comment: Try the following: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String) (`toString(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String)`) with parameter "UTF-8"

Comment: @JonSkeet: Fancy pictues means some symbols.

Comment: @ControlAltDel: it's all text.

Comment: That's still hopelessly vague - and you haven't answered the rest of the questions... importantly, what the encoding is.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo No there is no binary data. It's plain text only.

Comment: @JonSkeet Encoding is default.

Comment: @user3697669: And what is "default"?

Comment: @JonSkeet It is UTF8

Comment: Right, that's *starting* to get somewhere. And what *exactly* do you mean by "some symbols"? Please copy and paste them into your question, or post an image. Does the JSON include any non-ASCII text that may not be representable in your console? (All of this should have been in your original question...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the platform default encoding to read the file, which is *probably* encoded in UTF8. Check the actual encoding of the file, and specify the encoding:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("...", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Note that since you simply want to read everything from the file, you could simply use

```
String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(...), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Files are of which type java.nio or zaaa.com.google.common.io.Files ?

Comment: java.nio. This is all standard stuff that doesn't need any additional library.